# python reportlab categoryAxis label placement

Tags: python, reportlab

I've written a simple function that generates a simple bar chart from a single data series as shown below. The input data can be positive or negative, which when negative results in the category axis labels being covered by the bar (charts 2 and 3 in the code below).

I have searched the [reportlab graphics reference](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-graphics-reference.pdfhttp://), and on page 202 a bar chart with labels placed "low" is shown. However the command used to do this: bc.categoryAxis.labels.dy = -60, appears to be arbitrarily chosen. How would one know the negative offset if the input data is not known? Is there a way to identify the x axis location on the drawing and then determine the label offset from that location, or any other work-around when the input data is unknown?

Thanks for any guidance.

```
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing
from reportlab.graphics.charts.barcharts import VerticalBarChart
from reportlab.graphics.charts.textlabels import Label
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter

def vbar_one_series(data, xlabels, chart_title, xaxis_text):
    drawing = Drawing(180, 180)

    bc = VerticalBarChart()
    bc.x = 25
    bc.y = 25
    bc.height = 125
    bc.width = 150
    bc.data = [data]
    bc.valueAxis.valueMin = int(min(min(bc.data[0]), 0))
    bc.valueAxis.valueMax = int(max(bc.data[0]) + 2)
    bc.valueAxis.labels.fontName = 'Helvetica'
    bc.valueAxis.labels.fontSize = 7
    bc.valueAxis.labelTextFormat = '%0.1f'
    bc.bars[0].fillColor = colors.HexColor('#000035')
    bc.categoryAxis.labels.boxAnchor = 'c'
    bc.categoryAxis.labels.fontName = 'Helvetica'
    bc.categoryAxis.labels.fontSize = 7
    bc.categoryAxis.tickDown = 0
    bc.categoryAxis.labels.dx = 0
    bc.categoryAxis.labels.dy = -7
    bc.categoryAxis.labels.angle = 0

    bc.categoryAxis.categoryNames = xlabels

    bc.barLabels.nudge = 10
    bc.barLabelFormat = '%0.1f'
    bc.barLabels.dx = 0
    bc.barLabels.dy = 0
    bc.barLabels.fontName = 'Helvetica'
    bc.barLabels.fontSize = 7

    xlabel = Label()
    xlabel.setText(xaxis_text)
    xlabel.fontSize = 7
    xlabel.fontName = 'Helvetica'
    xlabel.dx = 90
    xlabel.dy = 5

    title = Label()
    title.setText(chart_title)
    title.fontSize = 7
    title.fontName = 'Helvetica'
    title.dx = 90
    title.dy = 175

    drawing.add(bc)
    drawing.add(xlabel)
    drawing.add(title)

    return drawing

if __name__ == '__main__':

    bar1 = vbar_one_series([1.0, 2.3, 1.8], ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                                 'Title 1', '')

    bar2 = vbar_one_series([-25, 50, 10], ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                           'Title 2', '')

    bar3 = vbar_one_series([0, -1.1, -0.4], ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                           'Title 3', '')

    doc = SimpleDocTemplate('H:/Desktop/report.pdf', pagesize=letter,
                            topMargin=0.5 * inch, bottomMargin=0.5 * inch)
    Catalog = []
    Catalog.append(bar1)
    Catalog.append(bar2)
    Catalog.append(bar3)
    doc.build(Catalog)
```

[report.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvdam.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional research, I found that this problem can be solved using the .categoryAxis.labelAxisMode = 'low' property.